# Why does Java, Android Emulator and Chrome crash complaining about insufficient memory even when I'm using 80% of the memory?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, java, crash, desktop

My main computer recently began to crash most applications after just a couple hours of usage complaining about being out of memory.

I'm running a Dell Optiplex 7070 with 16GB of RAM. I know 16GB isn't anything out of this world but in my experience it should be enough to run my setup. This machine contains my fullstack development environment, so I'm running mainly SQL Server, Visual Studio 2022, and Android Emulators via Android Device Manager.

When I'm running my mobile applications on Android Emulator via Visual Studio it often fails with a message that javac is out of memory and this file is added to the root of my .NET project:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 266338304 bytes for Failed to commit area from 0x0000000703600000 to 0x0000000713400000 of length 266338304.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (./src/hotspot/os/windows/os_windows.cpp:3386), pid=11788, tid=3400
#
# JRE version:  (11.0.16.1+1) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.16.1+1-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: com.xamarin.manifestmerger.Main obj\Debug\net7.0-android\android\manifestmerger.rsp

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700 CPU @ 3.00GHz, 8 cores, 15G,  Windows 11 , 64 bit Build 22621 (10.0.22621.1485)
Time: Wed May  3 09:06:07 2023 E. South America Standard Time elapsed time: 0.014083 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000001e60c77a000):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=3400, stack(0x000000cd12700000,0x000000cd12800000)]

Stack: [0x000000cd12700000,0x000000cd12800000]
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x62652a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x7b3249]
V  [jvm.dll+0x7b4938]
V  [jvm.dll+0x7b5013]
V  [jvm.dll+0x24fca8]
V  [jvm.dll+0x62383a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x617fe5]
V  [jvm.dll+0x307bac]
V  [jvm.dll+0x307a32]
V  [jvm.dll+0x30c746]
V  [jvm.dll+0x352b9f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3525d0]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2e4ba8]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2e5d06]
V  [jvm.dll+0x78d097]
V  [jvm.dll+0x78e81f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x35f8e9]
V  [jvm.dll+0x770000]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3cd40f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x3cf7a1]
C  [jli.dll+0x5207]
C  [ucrtbase.dll+0x29363]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x1269d]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5a9f8]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x000001e60a606010, length=0, elements={
}

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:
  0x000001e60c790800 GCTaskThread "GC Thread#0" [stack: 0x000000cd12800000,0x000000cd12900000] [id=9592]
  0x000001e60c7ef000 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Main Marker" [stack: 0x000000cd12900000,0x000000cd12a00000] [id=6356]
  0x000001e60c7f5800 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Conc#0" [stack: 0x000000cd12a00000,0x000000cd12b00000] [id=8444]

[error occurred during error reporting (printing all threads), id 0xc0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffe999a4377]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x000001e60c7760e0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x000001e60c77a000

Heap address: 0x0000000703600000, size: 4042 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Non-zero based: 0x0000000703600000
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 0

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (1 events):
Event: 0.006 Loaded shared library C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\zip.dll


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff76ec00000 - 0x00007ff76ec0d000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\java.exe
0x00007fff4cc90000 - 0x00007fff4cea4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007fff4b150000 - 0x00007fff4b212000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007fff4a660000 - 0x00007fff4a9fc000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007fff4a2b0000 - 0x00007fff4a3c1000     C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007fff33ba0000 - 0x00007fff33bb5000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\VCRUNTIME140.dll
0x00007fff346b0000 - 0x00007fff346c7000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\jli.dll
0x00007fff4b780000 - 0x00007fff4b92b000     C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007fff25d90000 - 0x00007fff2601e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.22621.608_none_a9444ca7c10bb01d\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007fff4aa70000 - 0x00007fff4aa96000     C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007fff4b690000 - 0x00007fff4b737000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007fff4cbb0000 - 0x00007fff4cbd9000     C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007fff4a0d0000 - 0x00007fff4a1e3000     C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007fff4a5c0000 - 0x00007fff4a65a000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007fff4b220000 - 0x00007fff4b251000     C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007fff33b00000 - 0x00007fff33b9b000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\msvcp140.dll
0x00007ffe996b0000 - 0x00007ffe9a23a000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007fff4b5e0000 - 0x00007fff4b68e000     C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007fff4ad70000 - 0x00007fff4ae14000     C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007fff4c560000 - 0x00007fff4c677000     C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007fff4cc40000 - 0x00007fff4cc48000     C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007fff37f50000 - 0x00007fff37f84000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007fff475c0000 - 0x00007fff475c9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007fff431d0000 - 0x00007fff431da000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007fff4afc0000 - 0x00007fff4b031000     C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007fff490e0000 - 0x00007fff490f8000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007fff449d0000 - 0x00007fff449e0000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\verify.dll
0x00007fff47030000 - 0x00007fff4725e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DBGHELP.DLL
0x00007fff4b930000 - 0x00007fff4bcb9000     C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
0x00007fff4aaa0000 - 0x00007fff4ab77000     C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007fff46ff0000 - 0x00007fff47022000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbgcore.DLL
0x00007fff4a540000 - 0x00007fff4a5bb000     C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007fff33ad0000 - 0x00007fff33af8000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\java.dll
0x00007fff44050000 - 0x00007fff4405a000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\jimage.dll
0x00007fff33ab0000 - 0x00007fff33ac8000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\zip.dll

dbghelp: loaded successfully - version: 4.0.5 - missing functions: none
symbol engine: initialized successfully - sym options: 0x614 - pdb path: .;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32;C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.22621.608_none_a9444ca7c10bb01d;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin\server

VM Arguments:
java_command: com.xamarin.manifestmerger.Main obj\Debug\net7.0-android\android\manifestmerger.rsp
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.26\tools\manifestmerger.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

[Global flags]
     intx CICompilerCount                          = 4                                         {product} {ergonomic}
     uint ConcGCThreads                            = 2                                         {product} {ergonomic}
     uint G1ConcRefinementThreads                  = 8                                         {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t G1HeapRegionSize                         = 1048576                                   {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx GCDrainStackTargetSize                   = 64                                        {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 266338304                                 {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MarkStackSize                            = 4194304                                   {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 4238344192                                {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MinHeapDeltaBytes                        = 1048576                                   {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonNMethodCodeHeapSize                   = 5836300                                {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonProfiledCodeHeapSize                  = 122910970                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ProfiledCodeHeapSize                     = 122910970                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ReservedCodeCacheSize                    = 251658240                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
     bool SegmentedCodeCache                       = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedClassPointers               = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedOops                        = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseG1GC                                  = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation        = false                                  {pd product} {ergonomic}

Logging:
Log output configuration:
 #0: stdout all=warning uptime,level,tags
 #1: stderr all=off uptime,level,tags

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot
PATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Arthur\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Rico Suter\NSwagStudio\;C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Programs\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\Arthur\.dotnet\tools
USERNAME=Arthur
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel
TMP=C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Temp
TEMP=C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Temp



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 11 , 64 bit Build 22621 (10.0.22621.1485)
OS uptime: 0 days 3:02 hours
Hyper-V role detected

CPU:total 8 (initial active 8) (8 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 158 stepping 13 microcode 0xde, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx, fma

Memory: 4k page, system-wide physical 16165M (3479M free)
TotalPageFile size 16165M (AvailPageFile size 100M)
current process WorkingSet (physical memory assigned to process): 10M, peak: 10M
current process commit charge ("private bytes"): 60M, peak: 314M

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.16.1+1-LTS) for windows-amd64 JRE (11.0.16.1+1-LTS), built on Aug 20 2022 20:09:04 by "" with MS VC++ 15.9 (VS2017)

END.
```

When the Android Emulator crashes and I get log message sometimes (not all times) I get this error message on the emulator:

[image]

Very often Chrome also stops the playback of something on YouTube complaining of lack of memory.

If that's actually the problem I can update to 32GB, but I find it weird, because I have this workload on 16GB of RAM for a long time. I also have this environment that sometimes I run on Parallels on a MacBook Pro with 16GB and also never had this kind of issues. On my MacBook I have the same and even more development tools, and never got this kind of error.

This might sound stupid, given the error message, but could maybe be some Java settings? I feel like the problems have began since I added an HDD as secondary storage to this machine.

This is the screenshot of the task manager on the memory tab. In the screenshot I'm running Visual Studio, debugging with Android Emulator with Chrome, Postman, and SQL Server running on the background:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the memory screen from the performance tab in task manager? Have you disabled the swap file?

Comment: Maybe this in the error file gives a pointer? `current process WorkingSet (physical memory assigned to process): 10M, peak: 10M` is sounds like it assigns a certain memory allowance for the process, and 10 MB is very little.

Comment: @Mokubai I added the screenshot.

Comment: You have 14GB of 16GB committed RAM. I think you've disabled your page file and that is the problem. Enable your page file.

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, I think I did indeed disabled the page file when I added the HDD because for some reason it wasn't allowing me to format and I probably disabled on both the SSD and HDD because I don't understand about this. Now that you've mentioned I've remembered. I'll try to enable the page file ant try again. Should I do on both drives or just the SSD?

Comment: How much memory have you assigned to the Java VM? You created this problem by disabling your page file.

Comment: Windows does not like running out of virtual memory because it allows (and fully commits) memory allocations unlike Linux and BSD style OSes which allow memory overcommitment without requiring allocations to be backed by actual memory or storage. Linux allows memory overcommitment and hopes that processes will simply not use it and goes around killing them if needed, Windows simply fails the original request when virtual memory is exhausted. The result is that Windows absolutely requires a swap file to be able to guarantee memory allocations even if they are not used.

Comment: SSDs are well suited for swap file operations. Just have one there.

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't changed the settings of the Java VM, I'm a .NET developer, so I let Visual Studio manage the Java/JVM backend.

Comment: The error is saying the Java VM heap is the problem, you have an Android emulator installed, and is the reason for the crash. So what is it set to?

Comment: @Ramhound per [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1782154/why-does-java-android-emulator-and-chrome-crash-complaining-about-insufficient#comment2783307_1782154) the most likely issue is that there is no swap file and so Windows is simply failing memory allocations when under memory pressure with emulators and Chrome running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your Task Manager screenshot I believe you have disabled your swap/page file. It is showing only the 16GB of physical ram and there is no sign of any extra virtual memory (the page file).

I can tell this is the case by the figures under "Committed" at the bottom where it shows you have 13.7GB committed of 15.8GB. That 15.8 is the maximum amount of virtual memory in the system and is the total of physical RAM and backing store provided by the page file.

Normally that figure should be slightly larger than your physical RAM because there should always be some size allocated to the page file or memory mapped files. On modern systems I would be surprised to see it less than 1GB even with lots of physical RAM. That it is actually less than 16GB suggests that there is no page file and that you have actually lost some RAM to buffers used to communicate with devices in the system (it is the physical RAM minus the "hardware reserved" figure).

You should enable the page file. Once you do that everything should function normally.

Windows does not like running out of virtual memory because it allows (and fully commits) memory allocations unlike Linux and BSD style OSes which allow memory overcommitment without requiring allocations to be backed by actual memory or storage.

Linux allows memory overcommitment and hopes that processes will simply not use it and goes around killing them if needed, Windows simply fails the original request when virtual memory is exhausted. The result is that Windows absolutely requires a swap file to be able to guarantee memory allocations even if they are not used.

Comment: I didn't run into anymore issues since enabling the page files. I guess that was it. Thnk you! :)

Comment: @adamasan you are welcome. I've added a short explanation of what figure specifically indicated that you have no page file. I don't know why I didn't say earlier, it's kinda important to know *why* I said that was the problem as much as what the problem actually was.